# Take a screenshot of webpage at intervals?

Tags: 12.04, screenshot

I need a way to refresh a certain webpage and have a screenshot taken approximately every 5 minutes. I'm new with Ubuntu, but willing to use terminal, etc. If steps are given, I've used it before, I just don't know how to go about writing my own scripts.

Ideally, I would have the webpage open, and the page would refresh and take a screenshot every 5 minutes. Any help with this?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate - if it is I'll merge the questions - can you confirm? http://askubuntu.com/questions/50958

Answer (score 5):

The screenshot app 'shutter' has what you are looking for.

In a terminal, do `sudo apt-get install shutter`

There is no GUI way to do this every five minutes with shutter, but we can make it do the job with the command line.

Copy the following into gedit:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 while true; do
     shutter --web='WWW-HERE' -e
     sleep 5m
 done
```

Replace WWW-HERE with the address you would like to screenshot. Now save it in your home folder with a name that you can remember and wish to call it with.

Open a terminal and do `chmod +x FILE` and then `sudo cp FILE /usr/local/bin`
Remembering to replace FILE with the name you chose.

Now you can open a terminal and type the file name you chose to start it taking screen shots every five minutes. To stop it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard. If you want it to keep going until you logout, you can just type the name you chose after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and it will keep going forever in the background.

To save the files somewhere else or with a special name you can add the `--output` flag to the shutter command(before the -e!). So change that line to read something like this for example:

```
shutter --web='WWW-HERE' --output='~/Shots/Web%Y%m%d%T' -e
```

This saves to  folder called Shots (must exist!) in your home folder, and names the file given the time and date.

Alternately you can open shutter and navigate to Edit > Preferences and select a directory there where you would like to save.

[image]

An example screenshot of today's google doodle is [here.](http://ubuntuone.com/48zfMvMh6j7BPrZUoShuc9)

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I haven't tried this but you could use something like scrot (to take the screenshot) and an "at" command to do the the trick. Here's two resources that might be helpful:

Screenshots from the terminal: http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-ubuntu-linux

Using the "at" command: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I once had a script to take a photo of my screen every minute and upload it. I've tried to create something similar for you here. As Mordoc mentioned, you can use [scrot](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/scrot) [image: Install scrot].  You will have to `sudo apt-get install scrot` first.

Here's the script.  The lines starting with "#" are comments, so I'll use them to try and explain it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^This first line just tells linux which script language to use.
#  We're using bash

# Because this script runs as a Cron-job, it runs as root and doesn't
# necessarily know which user you're logged in as.  For me, this says "use
# the default display, ie the first person logged in on the computer"
DISPLAY=:0
HOME=/home/vose
export DISPLAY
export HOME

# Create the screenshots directory in case it doesn't exist yet
mkdir -p /home/vose/Pictures/Screenshots/

# Delete any screenshots more than 7 days old.
find /home/vose/Pictures/Screenshots/ -type f -mtime +7 -delete

# Launch the browser (I use firefox for normal, so I'll use chrome for this)
# The "sudo -u vose ..." means "run the command as user `vose`".  You'll
# You'll need to put your username in there...
# The "&" at the end means 'launch in the background', so the script
# can keep going.
echo "Opening the browser"
sudo -u vose chromium-browser http://google.com &

# This records the ProcessID (pid) of the last opened program
# (chromium) so we can kill it later
pid=$!

# Wait 10 seconds for the browser to open and page to load
# On a slow computer/connection/webpage you may need to wait longer
sleep 10

# Take the screenshot using scrot.  Save it to this file
scrot /home/vose/Pictures/Screenshots/screenshot_`date +%F-%H-%M-%S`.jpg
echo "Created screenshot_`date +%F-%H-%M-%S`.jpg"

# Kill the browser
kill $pid
```

Before you try go too far, stop and see if this works.

1. First, save the script above as `takeScreenshot.sh`.
2. Then from a terminal, type `chmod +x takeScreenshot.sh`  (Chmod changes the permissions on a file, and '+x' means we're giving it permission to "execute" the script.)
3. Run `./takeScreenshot.sh` from a command line - this will run the script manually.  See if the file shows up in your pictures folder after doing this.
4. If that worked, we need to now add it to [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

At a command line, type `sudo crontab -e`.  (If it asks you which editor, choose Nano.  If you haven't used it before, ask around for some help).

In the file, you want to add a line at the bottom, like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/5 * * * * /home/vose/Scripts/takeScreenshot.sh
```

What this says:

- Every 5 minutes
- Every hour, every day-of-month, every month, every day-of-week
- Run "/home/vose/Scripts/takeScreenshot.sh"

(one small gotcha: make sure there is a blank line after your entry in the crontab.  The last line of the file gets ignored, so you need a blank line after your command).

Well, I hope this long post helps! There might be ways to do this without the command line, but you'll have to look around.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try this tool : http://www.domdigger.com/
 It's not every 5 minutes, but if one-hour interval is enough for you, it's perfect for your needs.